# How to keep single session using express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I've created a basic `/login` route, which validates the user and respond with cookie along with storing session in DB.

If the same `/login` route is called from different client, new session is created

My requirement is to keep single active (latest) session for a given user and invalidate the old.

I thought of following:

maintain `activeSessionID` property in user collection, everytime login is attempted, this value would be set. If user access with old cookie, the validation would fail and server can reject the request. However, the actual session isnt destroyed in MongoStore Session Collection

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: are you using any other library for the `auth`?

Comment: today I tried using `passport` for auth